# LookupError : Entry point 'XXX' not found in egg 'YYY', But XXX exists at egg 'YYY'

Tags: python, egg, openstack-swift

I'm currently look over swift, and i'm stuck on running proxy. Below is error which i faced when i ran 'swift-init proxy restart'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/swift-proxy-server", line 23, in <module>
    sys.exit(run_wsgi(conf_file, 'proxy-server', default_port=8080, **options))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/common/wsgi.py", line 386, in run_wsgi
    loadapp(conf_path, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/common/wsgi.py", line 313, in loadapp
    ctx = loadcontext(loadwsgi.APP, conf_file, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/common/wsgi.py", line 305, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 320, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/common/wsgi.py", line 59, in get_context
    object_type, name=name, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 450, in get_context
    global_additions=global_additions)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 559, in _pipeline_app_context
    APP, pipeline[-1], global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/common/wsgi.py", line 59, in get_context
    object_type, name=name, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 454, in get_context
    section)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 476, in _context_from_use
    object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/common/wsgi.py", line 59, in get_context
    object_type, name=name, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 406, in get_context
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 296, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 620, in get_context
    object_type, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 659, in find_egg_entry_point
    for prot in protocol_options] or '(no entry points)'))))
LookupError: Entry point 'tempurl' not found in egg 'swift' (dir: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages; protocols: paste.app_factory, paste.composite_factory, paste.composit_factory; entry_points: )
```

So I look through both egg-info and source file which exist at dist-packages.

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift-1.12.0.113.g076634e.egg-info/entry_points.txt

```
[paste.filter_factory]
formpost = swift.common.middleware.formpost:filter_factory
gatekeeper = swift.common.middleware.gatekeeper:filter_factory
container_quotas = swift.common.middleware.container_quotas:filter_factory
container_sync = swift.common.middleware.container_sync:filter_factory
catch_errors = swift.common.middleware.catch_errors:filter_factory
ratelimit = swift.common.middleware.ratelimit:filter_factory
keystoneauth = swift.common.middleware.keystoneauth:filter_factory
tempauth = swift.common.middleware.tempauth:filter_factory
list_endpoints = swift.common.middleware.list_endpoints:filter_factory
dlo = swift.common.middleware.dlo:filter_factory
name_check = swift.common.middleware.name_check:filter_factory
domain_remap = swift.common.middleware.domain_remap:filter_factory
proxy_logging = swift.common.middleware.proxy_logging:filter_factory
crossdomain = swift.common.middleware.crossdomain:filter_factory
healthcheck = swift.common.middleware.healthcheck:filter_factory
tempurl = swift.common.middleware.tempurl:filter_factory
bulk = swift.common.middleware.bulk:filter_factory
memcache = swift.common.middleware.memcache:filter_factory
account_quotas = swift.common.middleware.account_quotas:filter_factory
staticweb = swift.common.middleware.staticweb:filter_factory
cname_lookup = swift.common.middleware.cname_lookup:filter_factory
recon = swift.common.middleware.recon:filter_factory
slo = swift.common.middleware.slo:filter_factory
```

As you can see above, line 'tempurl = swift.common.middleware.tempurl:filter_factory' actually exists(I'm not familiar with egg structure, so I'm not sure that those line is sufficient for running.) After confirm those line, i found that tempurl.py actually exists at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/swift/common/middleware/tempurl.py. It looks like that everything is sufficient for loading tempurl.py. Where should i go to solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance for any helps.

ps. 
Every docucments i read use '[filter:tempurl]' for proxy-server.conf. But I faced error at below, So I changed it for '[app:tempurl]'. And I faced above second problem. First problem also comes from 'loadwsgi'. So I'm assuming that first problem is also related with this loading egg problem.

```
....
    object_type, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 587, in find_config_section
    self.filename))
LookupError: No section 'tempurl' (prefixed by 'app' or 'application' or 'composite' or 'composit' or 'pipeline' or 'filter-app') found in config /etc/swift/proxy-server.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken out the following lines:

```
#[filter:authtoken]
#use = egg:swift#proxy
#allow_account_management = true
#account_autocreate = true
```

Here goes my error output before it was fixed . For science!!!.

```
[root@controller005 swift]# systemctl status openstack-swift-proxy.service -l
    ● openstack-swift-proxy.service - OpenStack Object Storage (swift) - Proxy Server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openstack-swift-proxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-02-26 19:27:07 WET; 3min 10s ago
      Process: 20405 ExecStart=/usr/bin/swift-proxy-server /etc/swift/proxy-server.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Main PID: 20405 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net swift-proxy-server[20405]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 328, in _loadegg
Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net swift-proxy-server[20405]: return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net swift-proxy-server[20405]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 620, in get_context
Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net swift-proxy-server[20405]: object_type, name=name)
Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net swift-proxy-server[20405]: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 659, in find_egg_entry_point
Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net swift-proxy-server[20405]: for prot in protocol_options] or '(no entry points)'))))
Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net swift-proxy-server[20405]: LookupError: Entry point 'proxy' not found in egg 'swift' (dir: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages; protocols: paste.filter_factory, paste.filter_app_factory; entry_points: )
Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net systemd[1]: openstack-swift-proxy.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net systemd[1]: Unit openstack-swift-proxy.service entered failed state.
Feb 26 19:27:07 controller005.company.domain.xxx.domain.net systemd[1]: openstack-swift-proxy.service failed.
[root@controller005 swift]# cat /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/swift-2.3.0-py2.7.egg-info/entry_points.txt
[paste.app_factory]
mem_object = swift.obj.mem_server:app_factory
account = swift.account.server:app_factory
object = swift.obj.server:app_factory
container = swift.container.server:app_factory
proxy = swift.proxy.server:app_factory

[paste.filter_factory]
formpost = swift.common.middleware.formpost:filter_factory
gatekeeper = swift.common.middleware.gatekeeper:filter_factory
container_quotas = swift.common.middleware.container_quotas:filter_factory
container_sync = swift.common.middleware.container_sync:filter_factory
catch_errors = swift.common.middleware.catch_errors:filter_factory
ratelimit = swift.common.middleware.ratelimit:filter_factory
xprofile = swift.common.middleware.xprofile:filter_factory
keystoneauth = swift.common.middleware.keystoneauth:filter_factory
tempauth = swift.common.middleware.tempauth:filter_factory
list_endpoints = swift.common.middleware.list_endpoints:filter_factory
dlo = swift.common.middleware.dlo:filter_factory
name_check = swift.common.middleware.name_check:filter_factory
domain_remap = swift.common.middleware.domain_remap:filter_factory
proxy_logging = swift.common.middleware.proxy_logging:filter_factory
crossdomain = swift.common.middleware.crossdomain:filter_factory
healthcheck = swift.common.middleware.healthcheck:filter_factory
tempurl = swift.common.middleware.tempurl:filter_factory
bulk = swift.common.middleware.bulk:filter_factory
memcache = swift.common.middleware.memcache:filter_factory
account_quotas = swift.common.middleware.account_quotas:filter_factory
staticweb = swift.common.middleware.staticweb:filter_factory
cname_lookup = swift.common.middleware.cname_lookup:filter_factory
recon = swift.common.middleware.recon:filter_factory
slo = swift.common.middleware.slo:filter_factory

[root@controller005 swift]#
```